# Augmented Reality Marker Reader iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, image-processing, markers

I want to use 'marker reader' technology in my iPhone application (you have a piece of paper, you point the iphone camera at it and information is bein drawn up from it). What API kits can i use/are availible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest SDK I can think of is [ARToolKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/artoolkit/) which should help in a Framework Solution for finding Markers and deriving information. There are a couple of other Frameworks which could be used and I've listed below:

- [Layar](http://www.layar.com/development/)
- [ARToolKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/artoolkit/)
- [Popcode](http://www.popcode.info/)
- [SGAREnvironment](https://github.com/simplegeo/SGAREnvironment)